# MatDialog dialog from Angular Material is not closing

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on Angular 6 Application where I am using Angular material dialog box.
I am trying to close the dialog box on success after the data is sent successfully to the server.
I used

```
this.dialogRef.close(0);
```

or

```
this.dialogRef.close(0);
```

or

```
this.dialogRef.close();
```

but it is still not working.

**component1.ts**

```
let NewRegDialog = this.dialog.open(NewRegistrationComponent, {

  width: '750px',
  height: '500px',
  //disableClose: true,
  data: {
    email : email,
    regType : regType,
  },
});

NewRegDialog.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {

  if(result == 1){
    this.dialogRef.close('signup');
  }else{
    alert('Login failed') ;
    });
```

**component2.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit , Inject } from '@angular/core';
    import {  MatDialog  , MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

    
   ... .. 
   .. .. 
    
      constructor( private restapi: ServicesService , private dialog: MatDialog ,   public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NewRegistrationComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any ) {
    
   ...
   ..... 
   }
    
    
     user_signup(data) {
    
    
          let userData = {Email: this.email };
          this.restapi.signupUsingSocial(userData).then(
            result => {
              this.responseData = result;
    
              if (this.responseData.status == 1) {
                localStorage.setItem('token', this.responseData.data);
                this.dialogRef.close(1);
    
              } else {
                alert('give proper input');
              }
            },
            err => {
              this.dialogRef.close(0);
            }
          );}}
```

Comment: Can you be please more specific on which dialogue you are trying to close? as I see in your code there might be 2 dialogues one in component2 and one in component 1 as you have done `NewRegDialog.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {

  if(result == 1){
    this.dialogRef.close('signup');
  }else{
    alert('Login failed') ;
    });`  where is `this.dialogRef.close('signup');` located? your code should work fine on `component2` and dialogue should close.

Comment: The codes looks ok. What error are you getting? If u create a stackblitz demo, it would be easier to get help.

Answer (score 47):

You have this error because you open the dialog outside the NgZone.

An easy fix is to import the NgZone in the constuctor:

`constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModalComponent>, private ngZone: NgZone) { }`

and then run the code in the NgZone

```
onNoClick(): void {
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  });
}
```

this article explains what is an NgZone: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Resolved, Also Issues was not reflected dynamic data into dialog component where it was passed from the dialog component was called, Thanks @Nico

Answer (score 9):

For me, the solution was to ensure I was importing `BrowserAnimationsModule` in my `NgModule`.

Comment: should i add BrowserAnimationsModule in every module because some of my dialog components are in shared module

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
 <div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button (click)="close()">close</button>
 </div>
```

and in your ts:

```
close(){
   this.dialogRef.close(true);
}
```

Comment: It's ```this.dialog.closeAll()``` not ```this.dialogRef.close(true);```. See the API documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api

Comment: @ThomasDavidKehoe That depends what the button's supposed to do, doesn't it? `this.dialog.closeAll()` will close all dialog boxes, and `this.dialogRef.close()` will close that specific `dialogRef`. Granted, I don't really see what this close button has to do with OP's question anyway, since they're trying to close it programmatically.

Comment: You're right, MatDialogRef has a close() method, MatDialog has a closeAll() method. I got these confused.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and i resolved using NgZone, i read the Angular NgZone documentation: https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone

The error is because you try to execute a function outside of the Angular context, so the changes don't show in the user view correctly because it's outside the context. I had that problem because it's an asynchronous function and Angular is waiting for an answer, and the view doesn't show the changes until that answer. That's what I understand when I read the documentation for NgZone.The solution is to wrap this operation inside ngZone.run(), you make sure that it runs inside Angular's change detection cycle and reflects the corresponding changes in the view. This is especially useful if you're using NgZone in a context where asynchronous events are out of scope for Angular.

This is my code for that:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
constructor(
    public app: App,
    public service: EstadisticasOrdenesCompraServices,
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    public dialogRef: 
    MatDialogRef<OrdenesCompraEstadisticasDetalle>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
    this.title = this.data.titulo;
    this.listaparametros = data.listaparametros;
    this.filtros = data.filtros;
}

onNoClick(): void {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    });
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34457618)

Comment: Ok, im gonna update my answer and include the code for the question

Answer (score 0):

I spent many hours in this and what I figured out was that inside my popout I had a form that was triggering a error in the javascript on chrome console . When I resolved this form error my popup was able to close. My suggestion to you to solve this is error is that you can  try to replace the content from your modal by a basic one to test the close button functionality.

Go to https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples then select examples tab then check the code of the first sample in the button <>. Then replace the contet of your popup by the one from dialog-content-example-dialog.html

The should be solved now, I hope this works for your

Regards,

Juan

Answer (score 0):

If you have an error occurring in the ngOnChanges of another component it can cause this un-closable dialog behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Since in my case, i was just following the Material docs, i didn't import the dialog Component on app.module so the fix was importing the dialog Component on app.module

Answer (score 0):

On older versions of Angular, make sure you add BrowserAnimationsModule to imports in app.module.ts:

```
  imports: [
    ...
    MatDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ...
  ]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can close dialog from component where you have

```
let NewRegDialog = this.dialog.open(NewRegistrationComponent, {
```

In your example component1 have dialog.open method. Why you try close in component2?